# Java Graphics: setClip vs clipRect vs repaint(int,int,int,int)

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics2d

Similar to my last post apologies, but a lot less long winded. Basically I am wondering what is the best option for optimising redrawing to a JFrame/JPanel when each repaint call only a small part of the screen would be redrawn.

Also apart from overloading repaint I am not 100% on how to implement setClip or clipRect. My understanding they are used when overriding paint or update?
See below for some code:

```
public class AquaSim extends JPanel {
//variables
//other methods...
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g); //needed?
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Draws the land area for penguins.
        g2d.setColor(new Color(121,133,60));
        g2d.fill(land);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fill(sea);

        drawCreatures(g2d);
}
    public void drawCreatures(Graphics2D g2d) {
        for (Creature c : crlist) //a list of all alive creatures {
            //each creature object stores its image and coords.
            g2d.drawImage(c.createImage(txs,tys), c.getPos(1).width, c.getPos(1).height, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would prefer not to have to loop though each creature object each repaint request, which is part of the reason for this post. I dont know if there would be a way of sending the current creature being drawn to paint or overriding paint in the Creature class to get it draw itself on to the graphics object in the main class.
A bit more code...

```
private class Creature implements ActionListener {
//variables & other methods
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (getState()!=State.DEAD) {
                move();
                repaint(); //<---Would rather set clipping area in paint/update. x,y,w,h needs to include ICON & INFO BOX.
                //repaint(gx,gy,getPos(1).width,getPos(1).height);
            }
            else anim.stop();
        }
//...


  public void move() {
    //Determines how it will move and sets where to here by updating its position that is used in drawCreatures.
    }
}
```

So any suggestions as which would be the most efficient method to use? Baring in mind repaint will be called a lot by many objects/creatures i.e. many times a second, hence why I dont want it redrawing everythin on the screen each repaint request.

Comment: Swing is fully capable of redrawing many objects many times a second on a modern computer.  Generally in a Swing animation, objects are responsible for drawing themselves.  Your drawing code resides in the model classes, but is executed as a part of the view, maintaining a Model / View / Controller separation of concerns.

Comment: Indeed I expect the Repaint Manager would merge many of the repaint requests together. Just trying to make it as efficient as possible instead of just a straight repaint call each time, which would redraw everything on the screen. Any suggestions as to how to implement/inherit the paint method into the Creature class and then get each one to draw onto a global graphics object attached to the JPanel?

Comment: Take a look at my article, [Spirograph using Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=614).  Each object has a draw method.

Comment: OK thanku, tho that is a lot of code for me to get my head around so am still working out how you get a seperate class to draw onto the graphics object in your view class, as that is what I expect I need to do here. At the moment looks like Creature is the control class and AquaSim is both the model & control class. Would rather Creature be the control/model class and then AquaSim just displays it as a view class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> only a small part of the screen would be redrawn.

Use `repaint(....)`.

The RepaintManager will worry about what needs to be painted and will set the clip of the Graphics object for you.

Comment: Overloading repaint with the clipping area you mean? Which in this case would be current position of the image to its target position. Or did you mean the Repaint Manager is clever enough to know which graphic objects need to be updated/clipped without this?

Comment: The Graphics object has no idea what your custom painting code does. If you want to change a specific image then you need to give the bounds of that image. Keep in mind that if you update multiple images the RepaintManager will combine the requests into one paint request of the component and the clipping area will be the smallest Rectangle that includes the two images.

Comment: That would be what I am looking for, just for me to tell it each time repaint is called which part of the screen/window to update and leave the rest. Combining repaint requests is also fine so long as it doesnt clip half an image when they overlap or are next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest is it possible to make the Graphics object attached to the JPanel in AquaSim global and then from within each Creature object use this graphics object to draw to the JPanel?

Although I guess I would need to figure out how to implement/override the paint method within the Creature class a bit like Gilbert is trying to tell me.